# Logout Functionality not working immediately after login

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

am developing an application for android and ios both. But I am unable to logout from the application when I logged in once then log out then again login. After this moment the logout functionality is not working till I am restarting the application.

My code for logout is below-

```
ListTile(
  leading: Icon(
    Iconsax.logout,
    color: Colors.red,
  ),
  title: Text(
    'logout'.tr,
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
  ),
  onTap: () {
    Geofire.removeLocation(currentFirebaseUser!.uid);
    rideRequestRef!.onDisconnect();
    rideRequestRef!.remove();
    rideRequestRef = null;
    loggOut(context);
  },
```

```
void loggOut(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: true,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return ProgressDialog(message: 'logging_out'.tr);
        });

    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    GoogleSignIn().signOut();

    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
          context, BeforeLogin.idScreen, (route) => false);
      displayToast('loggedout_success'.tr, context);
    });
  }
```

It should logout the user

Comment: What do you mean by "the logout functionality is not working"?  How are you observing that it doesn't work?  Please edit the question to be clear what specifically does not work the way you expect.

Comment: Hi Doug, As I have written in my message that for the 1st time it is working fine but when I logged out once then again I logged in and then again trying to logout it s not working till I am restarting the application.